# Check if String / Record exists in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a String and I need to check if any column "item_manuf_id" in DataTable dtPs.Rows equals to certain value

I can loop over all Rows and compare

```
String id = dtPs.Rows[number]["item_manuf_id"].ToString()
if ("some value".equals(id)) etc.
```

but I am wondering if there is any way to check if `DataTable` contains the record

Comment: At the risk of sounding redundant, I'm assuming the OP is looking for a solution ensuring **constant** time complexity instead of **linear**, which seems to be what the accepted answer is providing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this

```
 string find = "item_manuf_id = 'some value'";
 DataRow[] foundRows = table.Select(find);
```

Comment: Great solution. As a side note, allow me to suggest a generic query format using brackets, in case your column name contains spaces (even though this does not directly apply to the OP's question): `string find = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, valueToFind);`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx) method if `item_manuf_id` is a primary key:

```
var result = dtPs.Rows.Find("some value");
```

If you only want to know if the value is in there then use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hc992ac.aspx) method.

```
if (dtPs.Rows.Contains("some value"))
{
  ...
}
```

Primary key restriction applies to `Contains` aswell.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over each row of the `DataTable` and check the value.

I'm a big fan of using a *foreach* loop when using `IEnumerable`s. Makes it very simple and clean to look at or process each row

```
DataTable dtPs = // ... initialize your DataTable
foreach (DataRow dr in dtPs.Rows)
{
    if (dr["item_manuf_id"].ToString() == "some value")
    {
        // do your deed
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a `PrimaryKey` for your `DataTable`. This helps in various ways, but you often need to define one before you can use it.

An example of using one if at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8(v=vs.80).aspx

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers");

// set constraints on the primary key
DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
workCol.Unique = true;

workTable.Columns.Add("CustLName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("CustFName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(Double));

// set primary key
workTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { workTable.Columns["CustID"] };
```

Once you have a primary key defined and data populated, you can use the **Find(...)** method to get the rows that match your primary key.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx

```
DataRow drFound = dtPs.Rows.Find("some value");
if (drFound["item_manuf_id"].ToString() == "some value")
{
    // do your deed
}
```

Finally, you can use the **Select()** method to find data within a `DataTable` also found at at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx.

```
String sExpression = "item_manuf_id == 'some value'";
DataRow[] drFound;
drFound = dtPs.Select(sExpression);

foreach (DataRow dr in drFound)
{
    // do you deed. Each record here was already found to match your criteria
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get away from this

Answer (score 2):

I think that if your "item_manuf_id" is the primary key of the DataTable you could use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx) method ...

```
string s = "stringValue";
DataRow foundRow = dtPs.Rows.Find(s);
if(foundRow != null) {
 //You have it ...
 }
```