# Filter Data in observable collection based on the columns in datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datatable, observablecollection

I had a `ObservableCollection` (fields like username,firstname,lastname,password,address,contact no etc) which contains a huge set of rows, and also I am having a datatable (columns like SNo, username,status) which is having a limited number of rows only.

Now what I need to filter the `ObservableCollection` based on the usernames present in the datatable in the datatable and bind the `ObservableCollection` to datagrid using linq.
I done a sample linq Query it does not produce exact data.

```
 var res = from a in Settings.GetInstance().ObservableClass 
           where dtStatusTable.Rows.Contains(a.UserName)
           select a;
 Settings.GetInstance().ObservableClass = res as ObservableCollection<IObservableClass >;
```

Note: `UserName` is unique and may be contains similar but not exact. Like usernames may be like Manikandan, Mani, ManikandanSekar etc.
Kindly give me a solution to filter the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961059/check-if-string-exists-in-datatable

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply eran otzap, but it is searching a table with a particular string, whereas what i need is to filter a huge set based on a small set dynamically using linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query says "where the datatable has a row of a.UserName", when it sounds like you want the query to say "where the datatable has a row that contains a.UserName in a specific column". You can make this a little clearer by doing something like this (not sure what your exact types are, so this is just some psuedo-query):

```
var usernamesInDataTable = dtStatusTable.Rows.Select(r => r.UserName);

var query = from a in ObservableClass
            where userNamesInDataTable.Contains(a.UserName)
            select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this which should select items with an exact match of `username`:

```
YourObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>(
    from item in YourObservableCollection 
    join row in YourDataTable on item.username equals row.username
    select item);
```

It's kind of tricky writing `LinQ` queries without data and intellisense, so please forgive me if there are errors in it.

Comment: Thanks for your time Sheridan. `Settings.GetInstance().ObservableClass= new ObservableCollection<IObservableClass>(
                                from item in Settings.GetInstance().ObservableClass
                                join row in dtRecentInteractions
                                    on item.UserName equals row.UserName
                                select item);`                        I tried this but it shows error in join

Comment: The error is that we cant implement the join in the above query

Comment: What does the error *actually* say? Surely there is more information than that?